# When setting up Continuous Integration Job, should I deploy only changed files in commit or All files in repository?

Tags: deployment, continuous-integration

I am setting up Continuous Integration and kind of confused as title says, whether to deploy only the components that are changed in the commit or all the components from repository?

Some people suggest that it is better to deploy all the components as a developer could remove certain method and if we just deploy that class, other classes could break that are referencing the removed method. Also, it forces everyone in the team to use version control as their manual changes could be overwritten next time CI job runs.

Which option is recommended?

Answer (score 9):

I *strongly* (but only partially) disagree with the other poster (sorry! :(). I think you should always deploy *all of the differences* between your repository and org. This is in contrast to deploying only components that have changed in a specific commit. The reason you don't want to deploy just changes in a specific commit is that it doesn't take into consideration the state of the target org, which causes a few main problems:

1. There's no guarantee that your org and branch were in sync before the CI job ran.
2. Any changes made to production (which shouldn't happen at all, but absolutely do with 95% of Salesforce developers we speak to) will be ignored. The big risk with this is that you might grow to rely on a change that was quietly made somewhere two months ago, but gets nuked by a CI job when the same file changes somewhere down the line. When you're deploying all of the differences, production changes don't live very long because they get overwritten by the next run of the CI job. This is a good thing because they're *timely* - the inevitable problem occurs close to the time that it was introduced, rather than an arbitrary period down the line when the reasons changes were made to prod (and who made them) have long been forgotten. Better yet, it encourages you to avoid production hotfixes altogether, in favur of pushing them through your release process.
3. If your repo and org aren't accurate reflections of each other, then rollbacks, disaster recovery, and even spinning up new dev environments and scratch orgs all become more difficult.
4. There are simple logistical issues - most CI servers queue jobs and run them in turn. Our TeamCity setup for building Gearset, for instance, will monitor our master branch, build that branch, and deploy the resulting artefact to our staging org when any changes are detected. If a build fails, then those changes don't make it out to staging. We then merge a couple more PRs to master (perhaps to fix the build failure) - TeamCity will dutifully build master when it spots another change, and push that to staging. If we were deploying *just* the changes in the actual commit, the first deployment would fail (let's say because of a missing dependency), but the second build triggered on merging additional PRs might actually pass, if those changes were to a different part of an org. Now our org's in a *really* inconsistent state - we've got earlier changes that were never deployed because of a build failure, and later changes that were successfully deployed. You'd need to look at your *entire* build history to know what state your target org is in. Contrast that with deploying *all differences* between repo and org, in which case your build will continue to fail until you fix the cause of the failure, and you always know that your org's state reflects the state of your branch at the last *successful* build / deployment.

Ultimately the goal of CI is to make your org reflect the state of your VCS, because your VCS should be your *source of truth*. If you're only deploying a subset of the differences between your repo and your org each run, then your source of truth is some ambiguous combination of the current state of your target org, and your VCS repo. You're essentially convincing yourself that you have a robust process, while losing some of the guarantees that a good CI setup is designed to give you, and this will certainly find a way to bite you in the ass.

Comment: Hi @mpd106 I respectfully disagree with you completely. Please read my edit to my earlier answer

Answer (score 1):

It is better to deploy only the changed components rather than the entire repository. The reasons for this are as below:-

1. Shorter time for deployment/validation which gives developers more time for fixing the errors.
2. Errors are thrown only for relevant component, if you deploy entire repository it may happen that components which are on older API can throw error and now developers have to fix this unnecessary error in a very less time and there is good chance that nobody knows the original requirement or the technical decision which went in doing the requirement in a particular way. If an attempt is made to fix it quickly it exposes the application to very high risk of failure when it goes into production.
3. Its developer's job to make sure there is no other class referencing a deleted method. If it causes any issues when deployed then its developer's fault and maybe the QA team for not doing proper NRT tests. Developers should also do proper unit testing to mitigate such errors

**Edit due to other post as my counter is too long for the comment**

*No way I would ever agree to deploying "all of the differences between your repository and org".*

This is a recipe for disaster.  A classic example is custom Labels, in any sandbox org we have org specific custom Labels which have either the recordTypeId (newly created), Sandbox OrgId, domain URLs, callback URLs to external integrations. 
So suppose if we have the setup the way you described where we deploy all the difference between repo and org then with each deployment at any time to a sandbox we are screwing up custom Labels(since production values got deployed unnecessarily without us committing the affected custom Label) and this can cause a lot of issues including severity 1 as entire functionality fails due to wrong custom labels.  Obviously, in our branches we will only store/commit the production values as VCS has to be aligned with the production org

I had a severity 1 issue and two bugs raised by testers just last week because somebody from the release team made a mistake(or it was CI tool itself I am not sure) of deploying our entire custom Label and it screwed everybody big-time leading to full-day loss of productivity.

This situation won't happen if we use the principle of deploying only the changed components

As per your example that somebody made a change 2 months ago then VCS main job is to keep track of who made what changes on which date and anybody can look it up and find out if we have to rap the developer for this mistake or it was a legitimate change.

Although mistakes(individual or tool) can happen but it always affects an individual component/s and very few people rather than your entire custom Labels, profiles or permission sets getting screwed each time you deploy.

Comment: Using Custom Labels to store org-specific parameters is really not best practice. That's what Custom Settings are for.

Comment: So in formula fields, you will fetch values from custom settings?
We can use custom settings in apex code but thats not the only use case here
What about using it on the Visualforce page, Lightning components, javascript, etc? We use custom Labels for many use cases and custom settings can't help in all use cases.

Comment: I didn't want to muddy the waters by diving into this in my post, but there will always be exceptions to deploying all changes, specifically for the reason you describe - configurational differences between environments (the sorts of things that would be handled by environment variables on more traditional platforms). These should be _excluded_ / specifically blacklisted (and potentially not even stored in the VCS in the first place, for things like API keys etc.), but they should be the outliers - everything else should be deployed from VCS for the reasons outlined in my post.

Comment: I just gave an example with custom labels and one can't just keep it outside VCS as it will frequently hold up deployments from VCS and you will have to assign human resources to take care of that. What's the use of VCS if you can't store/deploy all metadata types from it?
We use VCS to deploy every metadata type salesforce has. The reason why I insist on my approach is due to the bad experiences we had with the suggested approach in your post (when we started with VCS) and it was not limited to custom Labels. Maybe it works for your org but for us, it's asking for a disaster.

Comment: "What's the use of a VCS if you can't store all metadata types in it" is a little bit misleading - I'm not suggesting you exclude whole types, at most specific components of specific types. And there are other solutions to this problem, like having per-configuration apex classes that populate configuration-specific values from code, depending on whether they're running in a dev env, staging or prod. The point is these are two different problems - there are lots of ways to solve environment-specific values, and I don't think that pulling changes from only the last commit is a good solution.

Comment: There is a limit to 10,0000 components you can deploy, trying to deploy all to a massive org would fail

Comment: @PranayJaiswal True, but I don't think that's super relevant here - for last-commit changes, you need your orgs to be mostly in sync to begin with anyway, so we can assume all differences between repo and org would be comfortably < 10k. The only time you'd then have a problem would be new scratch orgs / wildly out of sync orgs, in which case you'd need a different deployment strategy in either case (like batching, etc.).

Comment: Might be issues with ci job that spuns up a scratch org, the diff is more than 10000 files, tries deploying fails.